# select where column1 are equals

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle 10.2.0 and I am new with it. I need a sql Statement

I have a table with 3 columns. in the column1 are numbers and same of them have equals values in column2 and cloumn3 are String.
How can I get the Strings from column2 and column3 together separated with ";" when Numbers from column1 are equals.

thanks

Comment: @Haythem: If a particular answer was helpful, you should vote it up by clicking the "up" arrow to the left of the answer provided. If a particular answer solved your problem, click the checkmark to mark it as the accepted answer. You can read the FAQs here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @Haythem - Don't know. I think it's cached. I've noticed before it doesn't update immediately.

Comment: -1: The grammar and spelling mistakes make it impossible to understand your question.

Comment: Please post some sample input and output data. That will be very helpful in understanding your requirements. (since it is the common language everybody here speaks :) )

Comment: I have this table  
cloum1 x      x    y
colum2 x21    x22  y21
colum3 x31    x32  y31 . I need a statement that gives me x21,x22;x31,x32 and y21,y31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ïf you have access to the analytical functions:

```
SELECT column1, LISTAGG(column2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column2) AS ConcatedValues
FROM   table
GROUP BY column1;
```

Comment: To illustrate Colin's comment, if you consider this answer was helpful, you can click on the up arrow at the left of my message, if this is the answer you were looking for, you can click the checkmark. (Note: I'm not saying you should do it, I'm just telling you how to...)

Comment: I give it a try and I have this error from the DB 00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: I think the function was introduced in 11g R2, which version are you using?

Comment: Try this if you don't have 11g R2 -----> SELECT column1, wm_concat(column2) AS ConcatedValue FROM table GROUP BY column1;